# Pandas timestamps to timeranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of 10 minute timestamps like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME_BIN': np.random.randint(1, 86400, size=10000)})
df['TIME_BIN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_BIN'], unit='s').dt.round('10min').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

print(df)

      TIME_BIN
0     07:40:00
1     01:40:00
2     12:00:00
3     06:30:00
4     00:00:00
5     04:30:00
```

How would I append the beginning of the range (subtract 10) and concatenate so that the column looks like this

```
      TIME_BIN
0     07:30:00-07:40:00
1     01:30:00-01:40:00
2     11:50:00-12:00:00
3     06:20:00-06:30:00
4     23:50:00-00:00:00
5     04:20:00-04:30:00
```

Comment: str can be paste together

Comment: Can you intercept your data before doing the `strftime`? If you had `datetime` instances you could then use something like `lambda x: pd.date_range(x - pd.datetools.timedelta(minutes=10), x)` (or something a bit simpler if you just want a string in the end)

Comment: Yes I have access to data before strftime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you are looking for:

```
import datetime

def timerange(a):
    return str(datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10))[-8:] + '-' + a

df['TIME_BIN'] = df['TIME_BIN'].apply(timerangeange)
```